# Finding the minimum value of a function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the least value of $f(x)=3^{-x+1} + e^{-x-1}$.

I tried to use the maxima/minima concept but it was of no use. Please help.

Comment: see the plot http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E%28-x%2B1%29+%2B+e%5E%28-x-1%29 and infer something

Comment: Were you given an interval...?

Comment: Generally one part should increase and another part decrease for max/min point to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $x\to \infty$ to take arbitrary low positive values for $3^{-x+1}+e^{-x-1}$. Hence $\inf\,\{3^{-x+1}+e^{-x-1}|x\in\mathbb R\}=0$

Comment: You first show that $3^{-x+1}+e^{-x-1}>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, of course.

Comment: If $a>0$, then $a^x>0$ for every real number $x$.

Comment: It is trivial, yes. still something you need to show.

Comment: Yes, but I just gave a hint to OP...

Answer (score 1):

$$ f^{'}(x)=-ln3.3^{-x+1}-e^{-x-1}$$
As $x \to \infty $  implies $ f^{'}(x) \to 0$
Better step using concept of maxima minima